# Apache proxy pass to unix domain socket

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, proxypass, unix-socket

**I need to forward all traffic from specified port to a Unix Domain Socket in Apache:**

In `sites-enabled/000-default.conf` I have defined a VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:8091>
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / unix:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/mysocket.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
    ProxyPassReverse / unix:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/mysocket.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
</VirtualHost>
```

In `ports.conf` I have:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8091
```

I have both `proxy` and `proxy_http` mods enabled:

```
krzysiek:/etc/apache2$ a2enmod proxy
Module proxy already enabled
krzysiek:/etc/apache2$ a2enmod proxy_http
Module proxy already enabled
```

I am using Apache 2.4.7 and offical documentation states that:

> In 2.4.7 and later, support for using a Unix Domain Socket is available by using a target which prepends unix:/path/lis.sock|

**When I reload Apache I get error:**

```
krzysiek:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2                                [fail] 
* The apache2 configtest failed.
AH00526: Syntax error on line 64 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
ProxyPass URL must be absolute!
```

I tried changing:

```
ProxyPass / unix:/var/(...)
```

To:

```
ProxyPass / unix:///var/(...)
```

Then Apache reloads correctly but forwarding **DOES NOT work**, error.log says:

```
[proxy:warn] [pid 22436] [client 10.0.4.19:47662] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Could you explain me what I'm doing wrong? Or how do I forward traffic from port to unix socket on Apache correctly?

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? I am facing same issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not :/ I needed to bind Python ASGI Daphne server to Unix Socket to be able to serve static files through Apache. I could not configure Apache to forward the traffic to UDS so instead I have bound Daphne to internal port and forwarded traffic to this port (without UDS). Yet in such config I am also serving static files via Daphne (not via Apache) which is not what I wanted :/ Maybe some Apache-geek will find some solution in future...

Comment: Try: `a2enmod proxy_wstunnel` with `unix:///...`. I have the same configuration as you and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late , but the following apache config works for me:

```
    ProxyRequests off
    Define SOCKET_NAME /path/to/my.sock
    ProxyPass        / unix:${SOCKET_NAME}|uwsgi://%{HTTP_HOST}/
    ProxyPassReverse / unix:${SOCKET_NAME}|uwsgi://%{HTTP_HOST}/
```

with modules `proxy` and `proxy_uwsgi` loaded.

**Important** do not place your socket in `/tmp` (I think systemd prevents the apache process to directly access it for security reasons).
Also, watch out for the file permissions.